# Is it better to call a method on a variable or chain it to the constructor?

Tags: java, methods, method-call

There are examples of calling such methods on any class.

I.e.:

```
SampleClass sc=new SampleClass();
sc.someMethod();
```

Or is it better to use

```
new SampleClass().someMethod();
```

Please, explain in detail.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Obviously the first is better if you actually need the variable for the object. Also, not sure why this is tagged with Android

Comment: tagged with android b'cause am i want to know any different while or any other solution when using in android

Comment: Java is Java. You have no Android specific code here. Yes, you'll see AsyncTasks do what you are describing, but you didn't specify that

Answer (score 3):

Both options are as good, but first one is better...

If you use

```
SampleClass sc=new SampleClass();
sc.someMethod();
```

You can call other methods of this class using same object of class.

If you use

```
new SampleClass().someMethod();
```

You require another object to call other method of this class.

---

Other example is

```
loop { // Here loop can be any type, for/while/do-while
    new SampleClass().someMethod();
}
```

this will create objects of same class as many times your loop execute. But if you go with first option

```
SampleClass sc=new SampleClass();
loop { // Here loop can be any type, for/while/do-while
    sc.someMethod();
}
```

This will not cause to create many objects to call method.

---

But Yes, if your need is to call only one method and that is not into loop, you can go with `new SampleClass().someMethod();`

Comment: is occur any memory issue when always use with `new` keyword and that is create always new instance..? @Pankaj

Comment: `loop { // Here loop can be any type, for/while/do-while
    new SampleClass().someMethod();
}` means this occur `new` instance every time so this take memory load for every instance..?

Comment: @Chirag.T Yes correct. And you should always take care about creating a new object. You should always think of the ways to avoid creating objects as less as possible.\

Answer (score 2):

Other than the obvious that `sc` remains an available variable in the first option that you can later call *instance  methods* on, both are perfectly valid without additional context.

If you have a *class method*, (in Java terms, a `static` method), on the other hand, the object doesn't need constructed

```
SampleClass.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you want to use anyother methods of SampleClass later, you might keep that variable (sc) alive in the instance. Otherwise,

```
new SampleClass().method();
```

is suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The first option allows you to access the object in the future again. You have a reference to it, so you will be able to invoke other methods of this object.

```
SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
sc.someMethod();
```

and later:

```
sc.someOtherMethod();
```